# Is shorter domain really better even it's hard to pronounce and recongnize but easy to spell?

Tags: domains, domain-registration

For example, I call **Andrew**, so I might want `andrew.best` for my site ), but and there is also another shorter domain called `a.best`, `a.best` is easy to spell, but it doesn't really stand out and good for recognize? Does it really worth it since the price has a difference for 1000 USD, and is it really good for a site?

Comment: There is a very popular comic strip hosted at xkcd.com.    The author chose short over meaningful.   It worked really well for him.  It helps that it is memorable.

Answer (score 2):

There are so many aspects you might need to consider while choosing a domain name.

1) It should be easy to remember.

2) Also, not too long and not too short.

3) The name should reflect the product or service.

4) It will be better if it will stand out in the crowd.

These are general guidelines.

It's very hard to say in your situation unless we know the details. But you may consider this.

If you spend enough time thinking about your product or service you may be able to find appropriate domain at a general price.

Also, if you are just starting something out then you may wish to get a normal domain and based on the success of your product or service you can do re-branding and you can purchase the expensive domain.

However, in some situation, you may have a feeling that the expensive domain may be the perfect fit. If so before someone else gets it, worth thinking about acquiring it.

Comment: I'm choosing domain just for personal blog or project sharing mostly blogging

Comment: If you are using it for a personal project, unless you are rich and/or famous, go for the cheap one.  You are unlikely to get your money back.

Comment: But as I want to make a personal blog, it might also has a e-commerence subsite, but in this case I have a site to launch/sell my project, do you think andrew.best is fine since it doesn't match stand out or unique name. Do you think it's fine to use andrew.best as my site with the following wanted feature?

Comment: For a personal startup, think about it and choose a domain and get started. There are tonnes of other thinks to think about when you start a project. I am not sure about .best, you could choose .com or the local country domain. As stated above, pick a domain which will describe your blog well.

Comment: Ok I'll take your suggestion and for the reason why I don't choose popular gTLDs like `.com` is b/c `Andrew` is a really popular name and`andrew.com` is registered and according to my experience it's hard to get a low/affordable price with a premium domain so I look down and find out `andrew.best` which is the best one that fit my thought, and for not choosing local country is I want to be global/international and I'm afraid I'll be blocked if I use my country's (Taiwan) ccTLD

Comment: All sounds good. Lastly, you may not need to think that you need to get a domain on own name. It can be related to the subject matter of your blog etc also.